# Initialize an ObjectListView with Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I have an ObjectListView with three columns. The first displays the name of a file, and the other two must have buttons that allow to perform download and delete actions.

However, to initialize the ObjectListView, I first call a method that returns a list of strings with the file names.

How do I get the names of these files to load in the first column of ObjectListView, accompanied by the buttons in the other two columns?

Thanks.

Comment: @TaW I am using the TreeListView component, which I downloaded from this project: [link](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html). Yes, I tried. I've used the component on other screens that I made, but in this scenario that I explained in the post I am not able to solve the problem.

Comment: Well, you really need to include that info in the question!! - As to how to use it you should rely on the docs and come back when have code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get the names of these files to load in the first column of ObjectListVie

You can use `AddObjects` to add a list of objects to the ObjectListView.  You can use `OlvColumn.AspectName` to determine what gets shown e.g. "ToString".  You might want to create a class instead of just shoving strings in though.

```
        olvColumn1.AspectName = "ToString";

        olv.AddObjects(new []
        {
            @"c:\temp\1.txt",
            @"c:\temp\2.txt",
            @"c:\temp\3.txt"
        });
```

> accompanied by the buttons in the other two columns?

You can create buttons in a column as so:

```
        olvColumn2.IsButton = true;
        olvColumn2.ButtonSizing = BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn.ButtonSizingMode.CellBounds;
        olvColumn2.AspectGetter =(s)=>"Kill";
        olv.ButtonClick += (s, e) => 
        {
            if(e.Column == olvColumn2) 
                try
                {
                    if(File.Exists((string)e.Model))
                        File.Delete((string)e.Model);
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("File not found");
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
        };
```